# Scale of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, preview

I am currently working on a QR Scan View in my Swift application.
I want to center the VideoPreview in the middle of my view.

The view looks like this:

[image: Image of the View I'm working on]

The view (white) is called `ScanView` and I want to make the image preview the same size as the `ScanView` and center it in it.

Code snippet:

[image: Setup of my VideoDevice]

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is a working solution:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView!
  var session: AVCaptureSession?
  var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
  var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createSession()
  }
    
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.previewLayer?.frame.size = self.innerView.frame.size
  }
    
  private func createSession() {
    do {
      self.session = AVCaptureSession()
      if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) {
        self.input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        self.session?.addInput(self.input!)
        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session!)
        self.previewLayer?.frame.size = self.innerView.frame.size
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.innerView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer!)

        //______ 1. solution with Video camera ______//
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        self.session?.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        self.session?.addOutput(videoOutput)
        self.session?.startRunning()

        //______ 2. solution with QR code ______//
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        videoOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        self.session?.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        self.session?.addOutput(videoOutput)
        // explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642852/2450755
        videoOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
        self.session?.startRunning()
      }
    } catch _ {
    }
  }

  //MARK: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
  public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        // awesome stuff here
    }
  }

  //MARK: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
  func setMetadataObjectsDelegate(_ objectsDelegate: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate?, queue objectsCallbackQueue: DispatchQueue?) {
    
  }
}
```

requirements:

- setup: `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`
- `innerView` must be initialized, I did by Storyboard with the following constraints:

[image]

here the result:

[image]

Comment: I tried it with 
`let videoOut = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()videoOut.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
                videoOut.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]` earlier in another application. it works there well but not in my recent. Any idea why ?

Comment: I meant that I used the same code in another app I programmed earlier. It works fine there with scanning for QR Codes.
The one im working on right now has some errors. I copied your code 1:1 but there are still errors left.

Comment: I see you are using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, so let's change `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`

Comment: I'm getting the same error using solution 2.
Is there any possibility to scan a CIImage for a machine readable code?

Comment: found the solution! try to move `metadataObjectTypes` after `addOutput`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem like Philip Dz. Finally fix the issue by moving the `setupVideo()` function from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`:

- call setupVideo() in viewDidLoad

[image]

- call setupVideo() in viewDidAppear:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am chiming in a bit late but I have just implemented QRScanner and, depending on device that is running a video stream can be zoomed. This is achieved via `AVCaptureDevice.videoZoomFactor` property. So, in order to enhance the user experience for a small square QRScanner, the above code can be slightly modified by inserting the following line `device.zoomFactor = min(YOUR_ZOOM_FACTOR_VALUE, device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)` before `self.session?.startRunning()`